# How to maintain two PHPSESSID cookie one for https and other for http in same browser

Tags: php

I am having a web application which sets session cookie PHPSESSID with flag HttpOnly, path and secure.  Secure is set only when https url is accessed.

If cookie is set by http request , same is getting shared for https and vice versa. How to maintain two different sessions one for http and other for https in same browser with same cookie name PHPSESSID.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an idea you're going to appreciate in the future.

Comment: I agree with @JaredFarrish, this is usually a problem that is telling you that you are doing something incorrectly.  Generally, you would forward all non-https requests to https and do everything securely.  If you do not for whatever reason, look at http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid or figure out a way to lookup the session idea when transitioning, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php.

Comment: Not only is [http deprecated in the browser](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/04/30/deprecating-non-secure-http/), but consider the impact to support; this creates two scopes that may be difficult to discern. Make the whole site https, it's basically free with Let's Encrypt. You might describe more what this solves for you specifically, so the appropriateness of solutions can be ascertained.

Comment: I'm going to agree with everyone else here: since you've got https already, then you should not be thinking of using insecure http at all. Switch to 100% https.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set 2 cookies with the same name for a Host.  Cookies are associated with a host or domain, and the protocol is not taken into consideration.

If you truly want to have separate session storage you would need to manually set at least one of the sessions to have a different name via [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php).

As for the HttpOnly flag, that is a semaphore for the browser, and has no active serverside behavior associated with it.  In other words, the flag may or may not be honored by the server.

A much more meaningful setting in this area is session.cookie_secure, where the server won't send a cookie over http at all, however, that should not be interpreted to mean it won't read a cookie.  If a cookie gets set in the browser, and the browser makes a subsequent request to that host or domain (if using a domain cookie) then the browser is gong to include the cookie data in the request.